# Why is kauth gone from heimdal-clients, and is there something to replace it with?

Tags: package-management

I need to authorize with kerberos and I have always done that with kauth. Previously it have been included in the package heimdal-clients but since natty it has been removed (see https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/natty/+source/heimdal/+changelog, git20101228). I have searched in ubuntu packages but didn't find it. Have it been replaced with something or did someone decide they didn't need it any more and therefore no one else does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right. I took another stab at this and finally found the solution, which is quite ridiculous: kauth is now more or less replaced by kinit, one can now auth with kinit.